# converting _io.BufferedReader to str for write()

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, popen

how can I get my write() function to accept my stdout = subprocess.PIPE output? 
I keep getting a Type Error problem.

this is my code:

```
with open("logger.txt","w") as fobj:                                         
    baby = subprocess.Popen('bash arguments', stdout = subprocess.PIPE,  shell = True)
    fobj.write(baby.communicate())
```

i get type error

and i tried with this, no error but the file is always empty

```
with open("logger.txt","w") as fobj:                                         
    baby = subprocess.Popen('bash arguments', stdout = subprocess.PIPE,  shell = True)
    baby.communicate()
```

can anyone help me? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the script's output to be written to `fobj`,

```
with open("logger.txt","wb") as fobj:                                         
    subprocess.check_call('bash arguments', stdout=fobj, shell=True)
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but i still get an empty file, i see the output in shell however this time

Comment: thank you!!, but does suprocess.check_call do the exact same thing as subprocess.Popen? and how does it handle larger data sizes? is it better than communicate()?

Comment: It's not exactly the same thing. `Popen` + `communicate()` would buffer everything in memory; `check_call` (or really, passing a writable file to `Popen`'s stdout arg) will just pipe directly without buffering.

Comment: i guess using check_call would be better in my situation then because iam dealing with larger amounts of data, though knowing how to have subprocess.pipe output to a text file would be interesting. thanks a lot for the help!